# What does "reckoning" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does it mean "bad loans"?

> The plan has several advantages. By forcing banks to recognize losses, it could trigger a much-needed restructuring of Europe’s overcrowded banking sector: Unhealthy banks would have to either raise more capital or shut down. By averting a fire sale into illiquid markets, the plan would limit system-wide losses and make the whole **reckoning** less painful. The bad bank could even turn a profit for the European governments that provided its capital.

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-03-06/a-bad-bank-could-be-good-for-europe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *reckoning* is literally a calculation—typically a calculation of the  total cost of something purchased, such as the bill you are given at the end of your meal in a restaurant.

In this context, then, the *reckoning* is the final cost or 'bottom line' of the "huge pile of bad loans that EU banks are sitting on". The author suggests that creation of a "bad bank" would in the final analysis reduce the painful impact of this debt on the system as a whole.